# Trigger updating a Contact field to match an Opportunity field

Tags: apex, trigger

I have never written a trigger before and I've only started to learn how to this week. I need to create a trigger that updates a Contact field, Contact Stage, to match the Opportunity stage. I know I need to create the trigger on the Opportunity, have it only fire when the Opp stage has been updated, and have it update the Contacts that are tied to the Opportunity via Contact Roles. I know I can also run into the issue where a Contact may be on multiple Opportunities and figured I would get around this by using the most recent update. Any advice?

Comment: The trigger will fire when the event (insert, update, etc) you are looking for occurs.  So you'll need to ignore the times when the trigger fires and the Opp stage has not updated.  You'll likely get more specific advice if you can post your code.